# esp8266 code for correctness of reset and overall performance

Tags: performance, c, embedded, arduino

Please review my code for the performance and correctness, everything works and we get visible wifi access points  by opening `http://esp8266_ip_addres/hotspots`  except on refresh the values gets duplicated. and does not reset as I have done in the else block.

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define HTTP_REST_PORT 80
#define WIFI_RETRY_DELAY 500
#define MAX_WIFI_INIT_RETRY 50

const char* wifi_ssid = "router_ssid";
const char* wifi_passwd = "ssid_password";

int mn;

ESP8266WebServer http_rest_server(HTTP_REST_PORT);

const int numParams = 20;
String params [numParams];
String string = "['Please Select'";

String toString(String my_array[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    string = string + ", '" + my_array[i] + "'";
  }
  return string + "]";
}

int init_wifi() {
  int retries = 0;
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi AP..........");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_passwd);
  // check the status of WiFi connection to be WL_CONNECTED
  while ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) && (retries < MAX_WIFI_INIT_RETRY)) {
    retries++;
    delay(WIFI_RETRY_DELAY);
    Serial.print("#");
  }
  return WiFi.status(); // return the WiFi connection status
}

void readParams(String (& params) [numParams])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < mn; i++)
  {
    params [i] = WiFi.SSID(i).c_str();
  }
}

int store_mn = 0;
String results;

void listHotspots() {
  if (mn != store_mn) {
    results = toString(params, mn);
    store_mn = mn;
  }
  else {
    mn = WiFi.scanNetworks(); // this is not resetting as expected
    params[0] = (String)0; // this is not resetting as expected
    readParams (params); // after reseting I expected to be new values of params
    results = toString(params, mn);
    store_mn = mn;
  }
  http_rest_server.send(200, "application/json", results);
}

void config_rest_server_routing() {
  http_rest_server.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
    http_rest_server.send(200, "text/html",
                          "Welcome to the ESP8266 REST Web Server");
  });
  http_rest_server.on("/hotspots", HTTP_GET, listHotspots);
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  mn = WiFi.scanNetworks(); // scan for hotspots for the first time.
  readParams (params);
  WiFi.scanDelete();
  if (init_wifi() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Connetted to ");
    Serial.print(wifi_ssid);
    Serial.print("--- IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error connecting to: ");
    Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
  }
  config_rest_server_routing();

  http_rest_server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP REST Server Started");
}

void loop(void) {
  http_rest_server.handleClient();
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Since this code does not work as expected, it is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Hint: `string` should be a local variable.

Comment: "Working code" doesn't mean it just compiles & runs, it also means code that *works as intended* - fixing your refresh logic is outside the scope of this site, please see [help/on-topic].